# Define nested oneof messages in a protobuf message

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

I tried to define nested oneof messages in a protobuf message. Can we have nested oneof messages in a protobuf message?

Thanks

Comment: What happened when you tried this?

Comment: I have the same problem. I get the error "Missing field Numer" on the first nested oneof. example :

Answer (score 0):

You can define a message with "oneof" that contains messages. Those messages may also contain "oneof".

For instance if I have an API which controls my hardware, consisting of a chiller and syringePump, and they each support their own actions, potentially each with different parameters, my API allows a single command to a single device and enforces only the correct parameters are used:

```
syntax="proto3";

message ChillerSetTemperature {
    int32 temperature=1;
}

message ChillerGetTemperature {
    bool noArg=1;
}

message Chiller {
    oneof command {
        ChillerSetTemperature Set = 1;
        ChillerGetTemperature Get = 2;
    }
}

message SyringePumpAspirate {
    int32 volume = 1;
    int32 speed = 2;
}

message SyringePumpDispense {
    int32 volume = 1;
    int32 speed = 2;
}

message SyringePumpSelectPort {
    int32 position=1;
}

message Syringe {
    oneof command {
        SyringePumpAspirate Aspirate = 1;
        SyringePumpDispense Dispense = 2;
        SyringePumpSelectPort SelectPort = 3;
    }
}

message Action {
    oneof device {
        Syringe syringe = 1;
        Chiller chiller = 2;
    }
}
```